# Golang: Mysql Prepare Insert statements do not add rows into db table

Tags: mysql, go

So I'm trying to use a mysql driver to insert data into a database.

Specifically, I'm using this one:

```
"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

This is my code

```
func main() {

    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "psanker:123@/education_data")
    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to prepare connection to database")
        log.Fatal("Error:", err.Error())
    }

    defer db.Close()

    content, err := ioutil.ReadFile("activities.csv")

    lines := strings.Split(string(content), "\r")

    //only work so long as I have one district
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id FROM districts")
    var districtId int
    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        err := rows.Scan(&districtId)
        check(err)
    }


    for i, line := range lines {
        if i > 1 {
            splitStr := strings.Split(line, ",")
            var activityCode string

            if strings.Contains(splitStr[0], "-") {
                //this is an activity
                activityCode = splitStr[0]
                stmt1, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO activities(code) VALUES(?)")
                stmt2, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO activities(name) VALUES(?)")
                res, _ := stmt1.Exec(splitStr[0])
                stmt2.Exec(splitStr[1])
            } else {
                //this is a sub activity
                stmt1, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO sub_activities(code) VALUES(?)")
                stmt2, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO sub_activities(name) VALUES(?)")
                stmt1.Exec(splitStr[0])
                stmt2.Exec(splitStr[1])
                if activityCode != "" {
                    rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT id from activities where code = ?", activityCode)
                    var activityId int
                    for rows.Next() {
                        err := rows.Scan(&activityId)
                        check(err)
                        stmt3, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO sub_activities(activity_id) VALUES(?)")
                        stmt3.Exec(activityId)
                    }
                }
                rows, _ := db.Query("SELECT id from sub_activities where code= ?", splitStr[0])
                var sub_activityId int
                for rows.Next() {
                    err := rows.Scan(&sub_activityId)
                    check(err)
                    stmt5, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO sub_activity_expenditure(district_id) VALUES(?)")
                    stmt6, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO sub_activity_expenditure(sub_activity_id) VALUES(?)")
                    stmt7, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO sub_activity_expenditure(expenditure) VALUES(?)")
                    stmt5.Exec(districtId)
                    stmt6.Exec(sub_activityId)
                    stmt7.Exec(splitStr[2])
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I check Mysql database, there are no rows inserted into the tables. I think I'm accessing the right database because the initial query that gets id from districts is returning 1, which is correct.

What's going on?

**EDIT**

I have confirmed I'm in the right db by doing this

```
rows, err = db.Query("SELECT DATABASE();")
var test string

for rows.Next() {
    rows.Scan(&test)
    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

Which prints out `education_data`

Comment: make a call to `SELECT DATABASE();` and see where you are

Comment: wait so db.Prepare("SELECT DATABASE()"), and then what?

Comment: then like execute it ?

Comment: got it, it shows that I'm in the right database, which is education_data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are trying to insert into a table, I was reminded (in chat at least) that your columns are non-null and you really meant to create one row when you were in fact creating two. It failed on `stmt1` and `stmt2` because non-nullable columns were not given parameters to replace for all necessary data for insertion to succeed.

Focus on creating one row for `stmt1` and `stmt2` (combine them into a single `stmt1` to execute with 2 parameters).

Make sure strings are wrapped with a single quote.

Comment: So I printed out splitStr[0] and splitStr[1] and they were both string values

Comment: those i can understand. it is the `districtId`, `activityId`, and `sub_activityId`

Comment: so I commented everything out apart from the stuff for stmt1 and stmt2, and still nothing. 

I do a SELECT * from activities, and I get this output -

mysql> SELECT * FROM activities;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: i believe that it is in the preparing of the statement (with 0 or no values in key variables) that causes the insert stmt to fail. Can you echo out during normal execution somewhere what the values are of the above 3 variables. i just don't understand where they are being set. For instance, where is `activityId` being set by you?

Comment: i say this as a non-go programmer so keep that in mind

Comment: well what if I replaced     stmt1, _ := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO activities(code) VALUES(?)")

with "INSERT INTO activities(code) VALUES(" + splitStr[0] + ")"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79701/discussion-between-praks5432-and-drew-pierce).